# Adding a image in a email script

Tags: php, image, email

I have a email script that works great but can not get a image to show up in the email with the contents. How can I get the image to show up in the email. I need the email to show up in the $template area.

```
<?php
//Fetching Values from URL
$name = $_POST['name1'];
$email = $_POST['email1'];
$message = $_POST['message1'];
$contact = $_POST['contact1'];
//sanitizing email
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
//After sanitization Validation is performed
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{10}$/", $contact)) {
echo "<span>* Please Fill Valid Contact No. *</span>";
} else {
$subject = $name;
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From:' . $email. "\r\n"; // Sender's Email
$headers .= 'Cc:' . $email. "\r\n"; // Carbon copy to Sender
$template = '<div style="padding:50px; color:white;">Hello ' . $name . ',<br/>'
. '<br/>Thank you...! For leaving your information with us.<br/><br/>'
. 'Name: ' . $name . '<br/>'
. 'Email: ' . $email . '<br/>'
. 'Contact No: ' . $contact . '<br/>'
. 'Message: ' . $message . '<br/><br/>'
. 'This is a Contact Confirmation mail.'
. '<br/>'
. 'We Will contact You as soon as possible . <br><br> Sincerely,<br>Prive Care Team.</div>';
$sendmessage = "<div style=\"background-color:#7E7E7E; color:white;\">" . $template . "</div>";
// message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
$sendmessage = wordwrap($sendmessage, 70);

// Send mail by PHP Mail Function
mail("cc-wp@hotmail.com", $subject, $sendmessage, $headers);
echo "Your Query has been received, We will contact you soon.";
}
} else {
echo "<span>* invalid email *</span>";
}

?>
```

Comment: just add `<img>` and `src` should be the complete address

Comment: Just use <img src='path/to/image' /> in the content of the mail :)

Comment: If you really want the image to be part of the email, not just downloaded when the user opens the email, you should use multi-part format with attachments. See: http://webcheatsheet.com/php/send_email_text_html_attachment.php Better still, use a library to do it, they take care of all the nasty bits, like spacing and the right amount of line-returns (yes, that can matter).

Answer (score 0):

In an e-mail (as any HTML page) there are two ways to display an image, either do it with an image hosted on the internet somewhere `<img src="src from the internet" />`
Or you can encode the image data in base64 and embed it like this `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS..." />`, that way the e-mail is self (not reliant on other sources on the internet) contained but will take up much more space.